# 500 Internal Server Error - Contact form

Tags: php

I am getting an internal server error when submitted the contact us form. Could anyone please look at the code below ?

```
<?php
$email_to = "sales@topmarble.co.uk";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$text = "NAME : $name<br>
         EMAIL : $email<br>
         SUBJECT : $subject<br>
         MESSAGE : $message";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: <$email>" . "\r\n";

mail($email_to, "TopMarble Contact Form", $text, $headers);
?>
```

> Server log: W3SVC574 P3NWVPWEB029 50.62.160.37 POST /Contact/sendCONTACT.php - 80 - 81.149.69.10 (Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.111 **utmt=1;+_gat=1;+_ga=GA1.3.1022338839.1454154856;+sc_is_visitor_unique=rx1030806‌​8.1454164056.5FE680C8F5B04F09E54B2D70E903ED0B.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1;+__utma=119944973.‌​1022338839.1454154856.1454154856.1454163827.2;+__utmb=119944973.6.10.1454163827;+**‌​utmc=119944973;+__utmz=119944973.1454154856.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|ut‌​mcmd=(none) topmarble.co.uk/Contact/index.html www.topmarble.co.uk 500 0 0 1637 961 1171

Comment: try using the external server

Comment: Faith, done put code in a comment, nobody can read it, instead, edit your question if you want to add more information. You can now DELETE the above comment

Comment: Server 500's are difficult enough to diagnose locally, so remote diagnosis is almost impossible. Try recoding, one line at a time until you add the line that causes the crash

Comment: You need to show us the server's error log. All you're showing is the access log.

Comment: Is the form and this scripts on the same page?

Comment: @Andy I am trying to find the server's error log. Yes, they are on the same page.

Comment: I removed the lines one by one and realized last line of the code (mail($email_to, "TopMarble Contact Form", $text, $headers);) is causing the issue.

Comment: Don't use the built-in PHP mail(). It almost never works. Use a library like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.